# when I move my laravel project to a server this error appears FatalErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 136: Class '\App\user' not found

Tags: php, laravel, web-hosting

I am trying to move my laravel project to a hostgator shared hosting (I have acces to the terminal but not as root so I can not install anything), I did it Separating my public folder from the rest of it, so in a public_html I put all the folders and archives that are in the public folder of laravel, and in another folder call laravel i move the rest of my project.

I already change this in index.php in the public_html folder:

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

after all this the home page is running just fine but when I try to sign in this error appears:

```
FatalErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 136:
Class '\App\user' not found
```

I do not know what to do.

here is are my routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'SessionController@create');
Route::post('/', 'SessionController@store');
Route::get('/logout', 'SessionController@destroy');

Route::get('/cliente', function () {
    return view('sessions.homeCliente');
});
Route::get('/staff', function () {
    return view('sessions.homeStaff');
```

and here is my session controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SessionController extends Controller
{


    function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except'=>'destroy']);
    }


    public function create(){

        return view('sessions.create');

    }
    public function store(){
        //intento de iniciar session


        $request=request(['usuario','password']);


        if(!auth()->attempt($request)){

                return redirect('/prueba');
        }

        //redirigir a donde se necesite

        if(User::getCliente($request['usuario'])==0){

            return redirect('/staff');

        }

        return redirect('/cliente');

    }    
}
```

I do not what to do.

Comment: Is it `user` or `User`? Some PHP instances are case sensitive, so you may be facing that, although there are no instances of `user` in the code you've pasted. Otherwise, try using `\User` wherever you are using this class, or add `use App\User;` to the top of your controller. Could be a namespacing issue, which either of these suggestions would solve. If none of that works, make sure you actually have a `User.php` model defined in your `app` directory, and try a `composer dump-autoload` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `\App\user`

It must be `\App\User`

Usually newbies are careless about letter case, because Windows basically ignores them; but Linux does not, hence moving to a server (which is usually Linux) introduces new errors.